# Python 3 Pandas Filter/Extract by multiple column values, including <> 0

Tags: pandas, indexing, filtering, conditional-statements, python-3.5

Working with a publicly available csv file from USASPENDING.gov.  Able to extract data from Navy but do not know the right syntax to add a second filter to exclude all records with `Dollarsobligated = 0`.

Code is:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("2016_DOD_Contracts_Full_20160915.csv")
df.columns = [c.replace(' ','_') for c in df.columns]
new_df = df[(df.mod_agency == '1700: DEPT OF THE NAVY') & (df.dollarsobligated <> 0)]

# Export result to CSV
new_df.to_csv('example15.csv')
```

I get an error that says `<>` is invalid syntax.  No examples of 'does not equal 0' on the web yet.

Comment: In Python2 `<>` was equivalent to `!=`. [In Python3,  `<>` was removed](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#removed-syntax).

Comment: Good to know, thanks unutbu :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need replace `<>` to `!=` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), because [in Python3, <> was removed](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#removed-syntax), thanks [`unutbu`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39830890/python-3-pandas-filter-extract-by-multiple-column-values-including-0#comment66951499_39830890).

Also you can use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ','_')
new_df = df[(df.mod_agency == '1700: DEPT OF THE NAVY') & (df.Dollarsobligated != 0)]
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'mod agency':['1700: DEPT OF THE NAVY',
                                 '1700: DEPT OF THE NAVY',
                                 '1800: DEPT OF THE NAVY'],
                   'Dollarsobligated':[1,0,0],
                   'C':[7,8,9]})

print (df)
   C  Dollarsobligated              mod agency
0  7                 1  1700: DEPT OF THE NAVY
1  8                 0  1700: DEPT OF THE NAVY
2  9                 0  1800: DEPT OF THE NAVY

df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ','_')
new_df = df[(df.mod_agency == '1700: DEPT OF THE NAVY') & (df.Dollarsobligated != 0)]

print (new_df)
   C  Dollarsobligated              mod_agency
0  7                 1  1700: DEPT OF THE NAVY
```

Comment: Glad can help you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use "!=" instead of "<>"